# Passing and reading an array with an object and array inside from JavaScript to PHP codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to pass an array that looks something like this below using a $.ajax() request.

```
[
    [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            age: "22"
        },
        {
            name: "Sam",
            age: "28"
        },
        {
            name: "Tom",
            age: "26"
        },
    ],
    [
        batch: "101",
        status: "live"
    ]
]
```

As you can see there is two arrays with one that is an object.

My question is how do I pass this to codeigniter and read the information.

Currently I'm passing it to Codeigniter by doing something like this.

```
    var submit = $.ajax({
        url:$('#hiddenurl').val() + 'index.php?/home/checkout/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {checkoutInformation: checkout_data_arr},
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
          //do code here
        }
    });
```

and my Codeigniter controller function looks something like this.

```
function checkout(){
    //send back Item details in JSON.
    $checkoutInformation = $this -> input -> post('checkoutInformation');

    print_r($checkoutInformation);

}
```

Currently this is the response from that function

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Bob
                    [age] => 22
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sam
                    [age] => 28
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Tom
                    [age] => 26
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, nothing to do with the second array that's in there. How do I parse thru the data with php to work with the data?

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to parse the json by client side ?

```
 var submit = $.ajax({
        url:$('#hiddenurl').val() + 'index.php?/home/checkout/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {checkoutInformation: checkout_data_arr},
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
            //echo obj[0][0].name;
// or walking through loop
$.each(obj[0], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});

        }
    });
```

Parsing on server side:

```
function checkout(){
    //send back Item details in JSON.
    $checkoutInformation = $this -> input -> post('checkoutInformation');

    foreach($checkoutInformation[0] as $k => $v) {
     echo $k . ":" . $v['name'] . '-' . $v['age'] . "<br>";
   }

}
```

Comment: No I want to parse it on the PHP side to do server side work with the data.

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: ok, i've corrected it, i thought $checkoutInformation is json but it was array.

Comment: The response looks something like this now. 0:Array

Comment: Hi @CarcaBot, yes I have. Still same response.